# How to draw 4 sides border around a bar in MPAndroidChart BarCart?

Tags: android, visual-studio, kotlin, bar-chart, mpchart

I am new to Android and am using MPAndroidChart to draw a bar chart. How can I draw a four-sided border around each bar in the graph that is displayed?

**Show bars like this image.**

[image]

and also bars should not be attached from the bottom; they should be drawn the same as in this picture, and they should shadow when clicked on the bars as in this attachment.

Thanks

I tried this, but it only adds the two top left and top right borders, and the bars are also attached to the bottom on the x-axis.

```
override fun drawDataSet(c: Canvas, dataSet: IBarDataSet, index: Int) {
    val trans: Transformer = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.axisDependency)
    mShadowPaint.color = dataSet.barShadowColor
    val phaseX = mAnimator.phaseX
    val phaseY = mAnimator.phaseY
    if (mBarBuffers != null) {
        // initialize the buffer
        val buffer = mBarBuffers[index]
        buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY)
        buffer.setDataSet(index)
        buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.barData.barWidth)
        buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.axisDependency))
        buffer.feed(dataSet)
        trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer)

        // if multiple colors
        if (dataSet.colors.size > 1) {
            var j = 0
            while (j < buffer.size()) {
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2])) {
                    j += 4
                    continue
                }
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j])) break
                if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled) {
                    if (mRadius > 0) c.drawRoundRect(
                        RectF(
                            buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                            buffer.buffer[j + 2], mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()
                        ), mRadius, mRadius, mShadowPaint
                    ) else c.drawRect(
                        buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                        buffer.buffer[j + 2], mViewPortHandler.contentBottom(), mShadowPaint
                    )
                }

                // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
                // is
                // out of bounds, reuse colors.
                mRenderPaint.color = dataSet.getColor(j / 4)
                if (mRadius > 0) {
                    val path: Path = RoundedRect(
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3], 15f, 15f, true, true, false, false
                    )
                    c.drawPath(path, mRenderPaint)
                } else c.drawRect(
                    buffer.buffer[j],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 2], buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint
                )
                j += 4
            }
        } else {
            mRenderPaint.color = dataSet.color
            var j = 0
            while (j < buffer.size()) {
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2])) {
                    j += 4
                    continue
                }
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j])) break
                if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled) {
                    if (mRadius > 0) c.drawRoundRect(
                        RectF(
                            buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                            buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                            mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()
                        ), mRadius, mRadius, mShadowPaint
                    ) else c.drawRect(
                        buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint
                    )
                }
                if (mRadius > 0) {
                    val path: Path = RoundedRect(
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3], 25f, 25f, true, true, false, false
                    )
                    c.drawPath(path, mRenderPaint)
                } else c.drawRect(
                    buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint
                )
                j += 4
            }
        }
    }
}

companion object {
    fun RoundedRect(
        left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float, rx: Float, ry: Float,
        tl: Boolean, tr: Boolean, br: Boolean, bl: Boolean
    ): Path {
        var rx = rx
        var ry = ry
        val path = Path()
        if (rx < 0) rx = 0f
        if (ry < 0) ry = 0f
        val width = right - left
        val height = bottom - top
        if (rx > width / 2) rx = width / 2
        if (ry > height / 2) ry = height / 2
        val widthMinusCorners = width - 2 * rx
        val heightMinusCorners = height - 2 * ry

        path.moveTo(right, top + ry)
        if (tr) path.rQuadTo(0f, -ry, -rx, -ry) //top-right corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(0f, -ry)
            path.rLineTo(-rx, 0f)
        }
        path.rLineTo(-widthMinusCorners, 0f)
        if (tl) path.rQuadTo(-rx, 0f, -rx, ry) //top-left corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(-rx, 0f)
            path.rLineTo(0f, ry)
        }
        path.rLineTo(0f, heightMinusCorners)
        if (bl) path.rQuadTo(0f, ry, rx, ry) //bottom-left corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(0f, ry)
            path.rLineTo(rx, 0f)
        }
        path.rLineTo(widthMinusCorners, 0f)
        if (br) path.rQuadTo(rx, 0f, rx, -ry) //bottom-right corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(rx, 0f)
            path.rLineTo(0f, -ry)
        }
        path.rLineTo(0f, -heightMinusCorners)
        path.close() //Given close, last line to can be removed.
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a rounded border around the bars in a `bar chart` using the  library. You've defined a `custom function RoundedRect` that creates a `rounded` rectangle path, and you're using it to draw the bars. To draw a four-sided border around the bars, you can modify your `drawDataSet`

**method as follows**:

```
    override fun drawDataSet(c: Canvas, dataSet: IBarDataSet, index: Int) {
        val trans: Transformer = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.axisDependency)
        mShadowPaint.color = dataSet.barShadowColor
        val phaseX = mAnimator.phaseX
        val phaseY = mAnimator.phaseY

        if (mBarBuffers != null) {
            val buffer = mBarBuffers[index]
            buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY)
            buffer.setDataSet(index)
            buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.barData.barWidth)
            buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.axisDependency))
            buffer.feed(dataSet)
            trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer)

            val borderWidth = 5f // Adjust the border width as needed

            var j = 0
            while (j < buffer.size()) {
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2])) {
                    j += 4
                    continue
                }
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j])) break

                // Draw the bar border
                mRenderPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
                mRenderPaint.strokeWidth = borderWidth
                mRenderPaint.color = Color.BLACK // Set your desired border color
                c.drawRect(
                    buffer.buffer[j] + borderWidth / 2, // Adjust position for the border width
                    buffer.buffer[j + 1] + borderWidth / 2, // Adjust position for the border width
                    buffer.buffer[j + 2] - borderWidth / 2, // Adjust position for the border width
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3] - borderWidth / 2, // Adjust position for the border width
                    mRenderPaint
                )
                mRenderPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL // Reset the paint style

                // Draw the bar
                if (mRadius > 0) {
                    val path: Path = RoundedRect(
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                        25f,
                        25f,
                        true,
                        true,
                        false,
                        false
                    )
                    c.drawPath(path, mRenderPaint)
                } else {
                    c.drawRect(
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                        mRenderPaint
                    )
                }
                j += 4
            }
        }
    }
```

**Fact:**

we draw the border around each bar by adjusting the position and style of the `mRenderPaint`. The `borderWidth` variable controls the width of the `border`, and you can change the color by setting the `mRenderPaint.color` to your desired border color.

Comment: It doesn't work, and I have tried these changes you provided, even though it removes the rounded borders from the top. I want to make the bars have a fixed width and show the center of the chart based on y-axis values with different colors; e.g., if the values are 80x150, then the bar should start drawing from 80 of the y-axis to 150 with the value 150 above the bar and 80 below the bar.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please provide me with the source code if you have already done this or if you can refer me to any document or example so I can read it out. It will be very helpful for me to do this.